# Module not found, but installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I tried to install the following, according to the given Installation Guide: https://github.com/JD-P/simulacrabot

But when I try to run the .py file with cmd, powershell or gitbash I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

I installed all the dependencies, checked and torch is installed, and even inside the cloned repo, but I still get this error

There is also a line which tells me to execute:
52a702409d76cd648be55a33de42aab188d676d9bfd23b5ef2ab5a8588c673c0  yfcc_upscaler_2.ckpt

But that long number text gibberish is not recognized as a command :(

Comment: When you open an extra console, you need to activate the virtual environment you installed the package into. Note how in the instructions you linked, the author also activates the environment with `source env_simulacra/bin/activate`

Comment: in the env_simulacra folder is no such folder as bin, so this fails. I looked into the files and found env_simulacra/Scripts/activate, which followed in the venv starting, so idk if its the problem

Comment: The instructions include this line `python3 -m venv env_simulacra`, which should have created a virtual environment that would definitely include a `bin` folder in that location (unless you're not on Linux, which is what the guide assumes) - on Windows you'd want `env_simulacra/Scripts/activate`. I would suggest looking for a quick guide or tutorial on virtual environments, you should understand a bit more about what you're doing instead of just trying commands you found on the internet, which can wreak all kinds of havoc if you're not careful.

Comment: Yes I use Windows, I tried using that command but it still wont recognize torch as an installed library

Comment: I just gave the other instructions on that page a try, and the packages being installed don't include `torch`, nor do they have `torch` as a dependency - so it should come as no surprise that it's not installed - why do you think it would be? You mentioned "the .py file" - what .py file are you trying to run exactly? The `simulacra.py` does try to import `torch`, so clearly the author expects you to have some additional packages installed, so you should try `pip3 install torch` - it's sloppy of the author to not include it in the dependencies though (or to not include a requirements.txt)

Comment: I did exactly that, but it says: Requirement already satisfied: torch in \simulacrabot\env_simulacra\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)

Comment: Then you're not running the .py in the same environment; if you get that message, you can just start `python3` and try the command `import torch` which shouldn't fail - that shows it's installed and you can import it. You should be able to run the script from the same environment - if you can't, you're leaving out something you're doing.